# R difference between order and reorder

Tags: r

I am trying to order a data frame by two columns, I can do this easily with order and I can see it works by printing it. However, when I try using ggplot it seems to ignore the ordering.

When I use reorder ggplot gets the ordering right. The problem is that I have not found a way to order by two different columns using reorder, just order.

So I have a dataframe with columns "name", "a" and "b"

**Using order**:

```
dfm <- dfm[order(dfm$a, dfm$b, decreasing=TRUE), ]
print (dfm) # prints correct ordering by two columns
ggplot(dfm, aes(x=name, y=a)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=tipo)) # plots in alphabetical ordering by name
```

**Order or by column a only, ggplot gets it right:**

```
dfm$name <- reorder (dfm$name, dfm$a)
print (dfm) # prints correct ordering by one column
ggplot(dfm, aes(x=name, y=a)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=tipo)) # plots in order by a
```

Actually I'm plotting a stacked bar, so y is not really a but a and b, but the ordering behaviour is always the same.

Any ideas? I have been struggling with this for some time now ...

Comment: `reorder` is used to, well, re-order the levels of a `factor`. `order` gives a permutation of indices for the variable given as input for a given sorted order.

Comment: ...and the way a factor is plotted in `ggplot` depends on the order of its levels, not the order of the data in the dataframe.

Comment: @Marius (...except for `geom_path`.)

Comment: @joran or  currently some implementations of `geom_bar` https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/721